# Удаление подстроки в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
new_str = str.replace(id, ' ');
```

`str` - это строка, например: 13 10 7 3
`id` - это подстрока( число ), которую нужно удалить.

Если `id` будет равно 3, `new_str` должна быть равна

> 13 10 7

Но я получаю такой результат:

> 1 10 7 3

Как я понял, это из-за того, что первое вхождение цифры 3, как раз таки в числе 13, поэтому функция заменила это число.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой функцией можно получить ожидаемый результат, а именно:

> 13 10 7

Comment: Какой результат ожидается для строки "13 10 7 33 7 3"?

Comment: Этот - "13 10 7 33 7"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо вам надо разбить строку по пробелам, после чего собрать строку заново на нужных вам условиях. В приведенном примере не включая те токены которые равны числу, которое вы хотите исключить. Т.е. должно получиться что-то типа такого:

```
var splitedStr = str.split(' ');
var resultStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < splitedStr.length; i++) {
    if (splitedStr[i] != id) {    
        resultStr += splitedStr[i] + ' ';    
    }
}
var new_str = resultStr.substring(0, resultStr.length - 1); // удаляем последний пробел
```

Comment: У вас пару ошибок в синтаксисе, но я думаю, что вы писали не компилируя. Но, метод работает, спасибо, вы мне помогли)

Comment: @ValentineMurnik да вы правы) я не компилировал, но рад, что вам это помогло.

Answer (score 4):

```
"13 10 7 3".replace(/\b3\b/g, "") === "13 10 7 "
```